# What does "facti" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, genitive, late-latin, corpus-juris-civilis

I am starting to read the "Novellae" in the Corpus Iuris Civilis and this sentence from the first one is confusing to read: 'et Tzanī nunc prīmum sub Rōmānōrum factī rēpublicā inter subiectōs habeantur'. It seems like "factī" here is in the genitive, but can't seem to understand it here. Not sure if hyperbaton is at play here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, *facti* is **nominative plural**, agreeing with *Tzani*, not genitive singular. You're right that the word order is a little strange, especially since *Romanorum* is separated from *republica*.

Here's a literal translation (including the *quatenus* that appears earlier in the sentence):

> [...seeing that] the [*Tzani*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zans), having come to be under the republic of the Romans now for the first time, are regarded among [our] subjects...

A couple notes:

- *Facti* is the past participle of *facio*. The passive of *facio* is often used in a special way to mean "become" or "come to be."
- *Habeo* often means to "hold/regard" someone in a certain light.

Comment: See, that is what I thought at first, but then in the next sentence I see quod and I thought then it referred to a 'factum' the noun, perhaps I glossed over that word's conjunctive senses. :P